# Parsing list items and returning a dictionary using comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a two-items list which I need to process. Those items are retrieved from a database, so the are actually **header: value** pairs but they are unparsed. They are strings separated by tabs, so the list looks like this:

```
my_list = ['header1\theader2\theader3\theader4', 'val1\tval2\tval3\tval4']
```

I need to create dict from the key - value pairs. Currently I do it with list comprehension:

```
keys = [k.strip() for k in my_list[0].split('\t')]
vals = [v.strip() for v in my_list[1].split('\t')]
return dict(zip(keys, vals))
```

I think there might be a way doing that using **dict comprehension** instead, but I couldn't get how. Is it possible to do parse the list items and return a dictionary with a one-liner or a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the solution below the most elegant one:

```
dict_comp = dict(zip(*map(lambda x: x.split('\t'), my_list)))
print(dict_comp)  # -> {'header1': 'val1', 'header2': 'val2', 'header3': 'val3', 'header4': 'val4'}
```

---

Alternatively, the `lambda` can be substituted by a *generator expression*:

```
dict_comp = dict(zip(*(x.split('\t') for x in my_list)))
```

and if the strings do not contain any spaces, it can be shortened even further to:

```
dict_comp = dict(zip(*map(str.split, my_list)))  # kudos @Chris_Rands
```

Comment: the most elegant would be not to use lambda: `dict_comp = {k.strip():v.strip() for k,v in zip(*(l.split('\t') for l in my_list))}`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The same ordo as mine, but splitting in a different step, potato potato.

Comment: @Ev Op specifically asked for a comprehension.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre why the `.strip()` calls?

Comment: because I was trying to improve the first answer.

Comment: @PaxVobiscum I wouldn't say so.. *"Is it possible to do parse the list items and return a dictionary with a one-liner or a more pythonic way?"*. he just says he thinks he can do it better with a dict-comprehension.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis the only interest _not_ using dictcomp is if you're stuck with python 2.6

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, you are right, I was only referring to the title.

Comment: `dict(zip(*map(str.split, my_list)))` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes, it works, but what if some items contain some spaces?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yah then you have a bug, personally I prefer the generator expression anyway; it does work in Py 2.7 Vinny

Comment: @Chris_Rands you're right, it does. What does str.split use for default? \t and \n?

Comment: @Vinny All possible whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this

```
dict_comp = {k.strip():v.strip() for k,v in 
               zip(my_list[0].split('\t'), my_list[1].split('\t'))}
```

Comment: not my downvote, but the expression looks a bit cumbersome. I would have done  `dict_comp = {k:v for k,v in zip(*(l.split('\t') for l in my_list))}` to avoid repeats, and you don't need strip.

Comment: why `strip()`? .

Comment: @Chris_Rands Simply trying to solve Vinny's problem more broadly. I cannot possibly imagine what he is doing with his code when we aren't looking :-)

Comment: @ChristianDean sure, but that's not the issue that we are trying to solve. If OP intends to use `strip`, by all means. I have to believe there was a reason to put it there to begin with.

Comment: Ah, I see! My bad @Pax. I didn't realize that the OP already had `str.strip` in his original code. In that case then yes, I do agree. One should strive to stay as true to the OP's code as possible.

Comment: @Chris_Rands because sometimes the last item has new line or a tab characters

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre your solution works on Python 2.7. I find it the most elegant solution. Thank you